# Por que este if no funciona?

Tags: python, condiciones

Estoy probando a hacer esto y no etienod por que este if no funciona, 
   pero la siguiente linea si se ejecuta

```
import pyautogui
a = "You choose A"
b = "You choose B"
c = "You choose C"
choices = {'Print A': a, 'Print B': b, 'Print C': c}
answer = pyautogui.confirm('Choose one.', buttons=list(choices))


if answer == a: 

    print("the if is working")

pyautogui.alert(text=choices[answer], button='OK')
```

Comment: Checa a simple vista, el bloque del if esta mal indentado

Comment: Si, ya lo he cambiado pero creo que el problema no reside ahi, si no que la variable answer no almacena el valor de la seleccion al apretar un boton

Comment: `choices` es un diccionario, con lo que a `buttons` pasas una lista de las claves del diccionario.

Comment: Entonces deberia hacer que se guarde la elección del usuario en otra variable y despues trabajar con la misma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según [la documentación](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/msgbox.html#the-confirm-function) de `pyautogui.confirm()`, al parámetro `buttons` debes pasarle una lista con el texto a mostrar en cada botón, y te retorna el texto del botón pulsado.

Le estás pasando `list(choices)`, y al convertir un diccionario en lista lo que te queda son sus claves, y no sus valores. Es decir, en tu caso, `Print A` en vez de `You choose A`, por lo que luego la comparación no funcionará.

Puedes usar `list(choices.values())` para quedarte con la lista de los valores, pero en realidad creo que lo que sucede es que has construido el diccionario "al revés" y que lo que querías hacer (a la vista de lo que haces más adelante) es:

```
choices = {a: 'Print A', b: 'Print B', c: 'Print C'}
```

Ten en cuenta que, si usas Python anterior a 3.6, al usar un diccionario no tienes ninguna garantía sobre el orden de las claves, por lo que los botones podrían aparecerte en diferente orden cada vez que ejecutes el programa).

Comment: Muchas gracias!! He conseguido cambiarlo

Answer (score 0):

El problema en esta linea: `Print("the if is working")` es que no esta indexada correctamente. Debería estar así:

```
if answer == a: 

    print("the if is working")
```

Ademas, la `p` de `print` debe ir en minúsculas.

Comment: Ya hice el cambio pero creo que el problema no está ahí. Tal vez no se quede guardado el valor de la variable answer o algo parecido?

Comment: Imprime 'answer' para ver qué valor toma

Comment: Me imprime = Print A. Es decir choices, pero no se como hacer el cambio para que funcione el if como puse antes